# Im trying to find the error in this code, testing my javascript-code

Tags: javascript

**Yo community!** might need some insights here.. :) I'm learning some more advance js-concepts. Im running this code but the result is not showing up as I was expecting..I can't see the error...any idea? thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function() {
        var results, queue = [];
        this.assert = function(pass, msg) {
            var type = pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL";
            var str = "<li class='" + type + "'><b>" +
                      type + "</b> " + msg + "</li>";
            if ( queue )
                queue.push( str );
            else    
                results.innerHTML += str;
        };

        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            results = document.getElementById("results");
            results.innerHTML = queue.join('');
            queue = null;
        });

        // calling assert but it's not showing up the <li> with the message....( why? ) 
        assert( true, "I always pass!" );
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen? What happens?

Comment: Works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/JDFuR/ - what browser are you testing in?

Comment: @nnnnnn everything cool, I just forgot to fill the <html-body> with the ul :) one question though...is there any chance that else-statement will be used? why is the idea of the else-statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *".is there any chance that else-statement will be used? why is the idea of the else-statement?"*

The way this `assert()` function works is that if it is called *before* the document load event has occurred any results are stored in the `queue` array: the condition `if (queue)` will be true because `queue` refers to the array.

Then when the load handler runs it takes everything already in `queue` and outputs it to the `results` element before setting `queue` to null:

```
results.innerHTML = queue.join('');
queue = null;
```

Any calls to `assert()` *after* the document load will then find that `if (queue)` is false because `queue` is null, so then the `else` will be executed and any results will be output directly to the `results` element.

In your code as shown, there is only one call to `assert()` and it will occur before the document load handler has run.

(Here's a clunky demonstration of this - presses to the button will be after the load event: http://jsfiddle.net/JDFuR/1/)